# Is it possible to get jsp variable from app.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

In jsp I have line `<c:if test="${suspensionInfo.suspended}">` but I want to read it from app.js from this function:

```
$(function () {

    if (!app.noticeModal) {
        this.noticeModal = new $.modal({
            closeOnSideClick: true,
            staticPos: true
        });
    }

    this.noticeModal.setContent($('#contract-suspension-modal').html());
    this.noticeModal.show();

});
```

Is it possible to do like that?

Comment: you can `var tmp="${suspensionInfo.suspended}";`